# Доступ к сигналу из другого потока

Tags: qt

Всем привет.
У меня класс который обращается к gui работает в отдельном потоке, и вроде нормально работало когда обращался к слотам.
Но мне теперь потребовалось реакцию на сигнал из С++.
В нужный qml добавил

`Connections { target: eventHandler; function onSignalAlertUserExists() {} }`

и вызвал сигнал.
И получаю теперь ошибку

`QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to EventHandler(0x55.......) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0x7ff.........`

Подскажите пожалуйста. С потоками я еще не идеально разбираюсь.
Спасибо.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Вот накидал простой пример. Если расскоментируете обращение к сигналу то получите ошибку. По кнопке же к таргету обращение работает. https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv6yi6mgq4ffx6s/untitled1.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: что-то не то пишете, GUI не будет работать не в главном потоке

Comment: Расскоментируйте там где в Connections вызов сигнала из event и будет писать

Comment: Ну что, получилось у вас увидеть ошибку?